# Google cloud monitoring. Log Metrics - no data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

When I create alerting policy based on a user defined logs-based metric there is no data in chart preview and generally alert doesn't work.

I spotted following details :

- for some metrics there is no resource / resource labels settings in edit popup
- for those metrics that allow to apply resource filters filling in all options results in chart preview load request hitting 400 HTTP BAD REQUEST error with following payload

```
{
   "code":400,
   "errors":{
      "filter":"filter exceeded length: 255 with length: 286"
   },
   "success":false,
   "error":"Field validation error"
}
```

Metrics created for a multi-module GAE/J application